# Flutter xcode build error File name too long

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I tried to build my flutter app in xcode and I got the following error - "File name too long".

I build at command line -

1. flutter clean
2. flutter pud get
3. go into ios folder and run pod install
4. flutter built ios -v

build is successful and no error found in verbose log. May I know what could be the issue.

```
/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner- ehbtgfrwszowthgqyvfzuynymnrk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app: File name too long
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Comment: have you cleared derived data first and then same steps as you mentioned ?

Comment: Yeap, I forgot to mention that I have deleted derived data first.

Comment: did you figure this out same issue?!